# is there any way to exit a program if author.id sends "(1/5)" in message.content:

Tags: discord, discord.py

Here is the code, i can't find a way to make it so if a certain user sends a message that contains a certain text program will exit

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author.id = 581122734306754595
        if "(1/5)" in message.content:
            exit
        if "(2/5)" in message.content:
            exit
        if "(3/5)" in message.content:
            exit
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You got some syntax mistakes, which shouldve been detailed in the error messages you're undoubtedly getting.

Also if you do the `await bot.process_commands(message)` like you did (inside the `if message.author.id = 581122734306754595` loop) it will only process the commands of the user you check for (<@581122734306754595>)

Syntax mistakes:

- if message.author.id **==** 581122734306754595 **:** `you forgot both the double == for comparing two things and the : at the end of an if statement.`
- exit ==> exit() `exiting the script is a function not a random word you just throw somewhere`

Personal advice: a discord bot might seem like a fun way to learn python, but it is mostly out of reach for a complete beginner, which you seem to be. Also get an IDE, which would help find these small mistakes(I use PyCharm, but you should compare the few that are available and pick yourself)